# Passing range from a RefEdit Control in a Userform to a Variant Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to pass the range specified from a refedit control in a userform to a variant array. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim y0 As Variant
    Dim X0 As Variant
    y0 = Range(RefEdit1.Value)
    X0 = Range(RefEdit2.Value)
    MsgBox (TypeName(y0))
    Call DataCheck
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

The message box shows me that y0 is indeed Variant(), however, when I try and do things like figure out the dimensions of the y0 or print it using a PrintArray subroutine I have (which has been works for other arrays), I get error messages. See below:

```
Private Sub DataCheck()
    'Check dimensions of original data
    y0N = UBound(y0, 1)
    y0k = UBound(y0, 2)
    'X0N = UBound(X0, 1) - LBound(X0, 1) + 1
    'X0k = UBound(X0, 2) - LBound(X0, 2) + 1
    Debug.Print "N y0 = "; y0N
    Debug.Print "k y0 = "; y0k
    'Debug.Print "N y0 = "; X0N
    'Debug.Print "k y0 = "; X0k
End Sub
```

I get a "Run time error '13'" message. Also, when I hover over this statement:

`y0N = UBound(y0, 1)`

I get a **Type mismatch** error.

Any ideas on what is going on here? Any assistance is appreciated.

Best,

Dan

Comment: Where are you passing the variables `x0` and `y0` into the Sub DataCheck?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please read how to create a [MCVE] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to scoping!

First, specify `Option Explicit` at the top of <s>the</s> *every* module; VBA should now complain that `y0`, `y0N` and `y0K` aren't declared in `DataCheck`.

The two variables are *locals*, in the `CommandButton1_Click` *scope*: you can't access them in *another scope* - and each *procedure* defines a separate *scope*.

The run-time error 13 is misleading; it's saying that because without `Option Explicit`, an undeclared variable simply gets "declared" on-the-spot, *at run-time*, and initialized to `vbEmpty`, as an implicit `Variant`. And since `vbEmpty` is of type `Empty` and isn't an array, `UBound` doesn't know what to do with it and throws an error that essentially means "I wasn't expecting that type".

So you need to learn to *pass parameters* instead - note that arrays *must* be passed by reference, so I'd recommend specifying the `ByRef` modifier explicitly (`ByRef` is implicit if not specified):

```
Private Sub DataCheck(ByRef xArray As Variant, ByRef yArray As Variant)
    '...
End Sub
```

And now instead of:

```
Call DataCheck
```

You have:

```
DataCheck x0, y0
```

(the `Call` keyword has been obsolete for 20 years)